# Как сделать проверку на несуществующий путь route и убрать exact, который ставится автоматически в react-route v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Вопрос 1.
Необходимо сделать, чтобы при вводе несуществующего пути перекидывало либо на страницу, которая об этом говорит, либо на стартовую страницу через route?
Мой код:

```
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/*' element={!!email ? <Navigate to='contentPage'/> : <Navigate to='authorization/login'/>}/>
                    <Route path='/contentPage' element={!!email ? <ContentPage/> : <Navigate to='authorization/login'/>}/>
                    <Route path='/authorization/login' element={!!email ? <Navigate to='contentPage'/> : <LogInPage/>}/>
                    <Route path='/authorization/registration' element={!!email ? <Navigate to='contentPage'/> : <RegistrationForm/>}/>
                    <Route path='/authorization/forgetPassword' element={!!email ? <Navigate to='contentPage'/> : <ForgetPassword/>}/>
                    <Route path='/contentPage' element={<ContentPage/>}/>
                </Routes>
```

Вопрос 2.
Как убрать exact который ставится автоматически в react router 6, так как мне нужно, чтобы header отображался не только при пути /contentPage, но и при других роутах содержащих /contentPage

Answer (score 0):

<Route path="*" element={} />

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]